# How can I return rows from an SQL query where one unique ID satisfies conditions in different rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `users` which has a foreign key in my other table, `usersHaveSocialMediaFans`.

`usersHaveSocialMediaFans` has columns:

```
socialMediaId, userId, fanCount
```

I need to find all users that have a fan count greater than (or less than) a certain amount *for each* social media. Admins need to be able to filter out all users that might have at least 6 Facebook fans AND 7 Twitter followers.

It was super easy when I had this information in my user table:

```
userId, ..., facebookFans, twitterFollowers, ...

---0--, ---, -----10-----, ------1000------, ...
```

Then, I could just `SELECT userId from users WHERE facebookFans > # AND twitterFollowers > #;` however, now my data for each user is split up into multiple rows and I don't know how to handle the logic. I feel like there must be a simple answer, but I just can't think of it right now.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `JOIN` to your `usersHaveSocialMediaFans` table twice for it.  For example, if you wanted those with more than 1,000 Facebook fans, and more than 10 Twitter fans, you could do the following:

```
Select  Distinct U.UserId
From    Users                       U
Join    usersHaveSocialMediaFans    F   On  F.UserId = U.UserId 
                                        And F.socialMediaId = <FacebookSocialMediaId>
Join    usersHaveSocialMediaFans    T   On  T.UserId = U.UserId
                                        And T.socialMediaId = <TwitterSocialMediaId>
Where   F.fanCount > 1000
And     T.fanCount > 10;
```

If you have another table that stores the name of the SocialMediaId for each platform, you should do another `JOIN` there instead of hard-coding in the `SocialMediaId`'s for each platform.  But I don't know your schema, so hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

If, hypothetically, you had another table named `SocialMedia` that had the `SocialMediaId` and `Name` of each platform, you could do the following:

```
Select  Distinct U.UserId
From    Users                       U
Join    usersHaveSocialMediaFans    F   On  F.UserId = U.UserId 
Join    SocialMedia                 SF  On  SF.SocialMediaId = F.SocialMediaId
                                        And SF.Name = 'Facebook'
Join    usersHaveSocialMediaFans    T   On  T.UserId = U.UserId
Join    SocialMedia                 ST  On  ST.SocialMediaId = T.SocialMediaId
                                        And ST.Name = 'Twitter'
Where   F.fanCount > 1000
And     T.fanCount > 10;
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That produces the right results. It's a dynamically created query based on the parameters that the admin selects, so thankfully the ID's will be hidden from any human interaction.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it

```
SELECT U.userId, F.SocialMediaID, F.fanCount from users U 
LEFT JOIN usersHaveSocialMediaFans F
ON F.Userid = U.Userid
WHERE (F.SocialMediaID='Facebook' and Fancount>1000) 
And (F.SocialMediaID='Twitter' and Fancount>1000)
```

another way to do it:

```
SELECT U.userId, F.fanCount "FacebookFan", t.fanCount "TwitterFan" from users U 
LEFT JOIN usersHaveSocialMediaFans F 
ON F.Userid = U.Userid and F.SocialMediaID= 'Facebook'
LEFT JOIN usersHaveSocialMediaFans T
ON T.Userid = U.Userid and T.SocialMediaID= 'Twitter'
WHERE F.FanCount > 1000 and T.FanCount > 1000
```

Comment: That second way of doing it would work out, I assume, since it's pretty much the same as the other guy's answer; however, I couldn't get the first one to work. Thanks for the answer though!